# How to retrieve a message from a repository with C# WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm still learning how to use properly Dependencies with C# and WebApi and I came up with a problem. I have a repository where I register a user but since is a `async task` void method it doesn't return nothing. So the question is, what is the best way to do this? It would be with `Task<T>` and handling the result in the Controller ?

The Classes :

```
public interface IGeneral
{
    Task RegisterAsync(UserModel model);
}

public class General : BaseRepository, IGeneral
{
    public General(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public async Task RegisterAsync(UserModel model)
    {
        var result = await Context.User.Where(a => a.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if(result != null)
        {
            await Context.User.AddAsync(new Data.Access.Models.User 
            { Date = DateTime.Now, Email = model.Email, Name = model.Name, Password = model.Password });
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
        
    }
}

public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    protected readonly Context Context;

    public BaseRepository(Context context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution that you have suggested in your question - would be the approach I would use.

```
    public async Task<bool> RegisterAsync(UserModel model)
    {
        bool operationResult = false;
        var result = await Context.User.Where(a => a.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (result != null)
        {
            await Context.User.AddAsync(new Data.Access.Models.User
                { Date = DateTime.Now, Email = model.Email, Name = model.Name, Password = model.Password });
            if(await Context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
            {
               operationResult = true;
            }

        }
    
     return operationResult;
    }
```

From MSDN documentation we know that `SaveChangesAsync()`  signature
`public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> SaveChangesAsync ();`

returns an int value.

Checking for a result greater than zero assert that changes have occurred and they have being made persistent.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Task<T>` return type of `RegisterAsync(UserModel model)` method to handle result in the controller because

1. you have to handle exception in `RegisterAsync` method and you can return bool return type in result but in production, you have to write log for these exceptions when you catch it.
2. It's not a good way to do this in repository methods.
3. Repostiory should have a single responsibility.

**You can keep this method as it is and can use try catch block in your services or in controller appropriately, depends on what you want to send at the time of exception by considering types of clients(Users)***